# When app is onAppBackgrounded I need to upload data to server android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, jobintentservice

I need to upload the data to the server in a different thread (not on the main thread). I have tried WorkManager to do this job like below. But WorkManager is not getting triggered every time I background the app. How can I send the data to the server in a different thread while the app goes to the background every time?

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
...
mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploaddWorker.class).setConstraints(
                new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(
                        NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()).build();
...
}


@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onAppBackgrounded() {
        //App in background
        Log.e(TAG, "onAppBackgrounded");
        mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enqueue the work is possible for it to start. It does not mean: "start now". For a work to start all the constraints must be satisfied. It depends on a lot of stuff and some of the constraints do not depend on your input, but also on battery optimization, etc.

If you want to start now go with a Service. Here you can read more about Background execution and how to pick:

https://developer.android.com/guide/background
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

If you want to go in the direction of the WorkManager you need to read about StandbyBuckets. Also, try to debug the JobScheduler and see why a work is not running:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Also, you need to understand Battery optimization:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

And how to disable it:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases

And this:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details